# how to parse text into tab separated columns?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a text file with lines that look like this

```
rnd-1_family-262#Unknown
rnd-1_family-263#LINE/I-Jockey
rnd-1_family-264#Unknown
rnd-1_family-265#DNA/TcMar-Mariner
```

and I want to get it into something like this, which is separate the text after the `#` and the `/` into `tab-separated columns`, with 2 'Unknowns' appearing when there is a single unknown ...

```
rnd-1_family-262 Unknown Unknown
rnd-1_family-263 LINE Jockey
rnd-1_family-264 Unknown Unknown
rnd-1_family-265 DNA TcMar-Mariner
```

I would appreciate any advice on how to do this in bash.

I attempted this in a round about way:

```
# gets the ID names
cat te-hierarchy.txt | awk -F '#' '{print $1}' > names.txt
# gets the stuff after the #
cat te-hierarchy.txt | awk -F '#' '{print $2}' > types.txt
# split that file to get 2 separate files 
cat types.txt | awk -F '/' '{print $1}' > order.txt
cat types.txt | awk -F '/' '{print $2}' > family.txt
# paste to create 3 cols
paste names.txt family.txt order.txt
```

However this means that there are blank spaces where there should be unknowns, how to insert this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this awk:

```sh
awk -F '[#/]' -v OFS='\t' 'NF == 2 {$3 = "Unknown"} {$1=$1} 1' file

rnd-1_family-262  Unknown  Unknown
rnd-1_family-263  LINE     I-Jockey
rnd-1_family-264  Unknown  Unknown
rnd-1_family-265  DNA      TcMar-Mariner
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to separator the text using bash:

```
IN="rnd-1_family-262#Unknown"
arrIN=(${IN//#/ })
echo ${arrIN[1]}
```

Comment: The rest of the code to apply that code snippet to the contents of a file would be a shell while-read loop so please read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) to understand some of the reasons not to do that. Also copy/paste your code into http://shellcheck.net and it'll tell you about other issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
rnd-1_family-262#Unknown
rnd-1_family-263#LINE/I-Jockey
rnd-1_family-264#Unknown
rnd-1_family-265#DNA/TcMar-Mariner
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="#|/";OFS="\t"}{$3=$3?$3:"Unknown";print}' file.txt
```

output

```
rnd-1_family-262    Unknown Unknown
rnd-1_family-263    LINE    I-Jockey
rnd-1_family-264    Unknown Unknown
rnd-1_family-265    DNA TcMar-Mariner
```

Explanation: I set field seperator to `#` or (`|`) `/` and output field seperator to tab. Then I set third column content (`$3`) to be either third column content or `Unknown` using ternary operator. Disclaimer: I assumed third column content is never `0`.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*